# PHP: If a equals b or c or d

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Short hand to do something like: if($variable == 1 || $variable == “whatever” || $variable == '492') .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205377/short-hand-to-do-something-like-ifvariable-1-variable-whatever)

Is this

```
if ($a==b||$a==c||$a==$d){ ...
```

the shortest way to describe this logic.
I am thinking about something like

```
if ($a==($b||$c||$d)) { ...
```

but that is not a valid code. Any suggestions?

Comment: what's wrong with this method?

Comment: THis is not correct because you are try to do boolean or with || between non boolean values.

Comment: Use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array).

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to avoid repetitions to make code more understandable.

Comment: In the new php update, you can also use this method
``$variable = "492" ;
if($variable  == 1 || "whatever" || '492'){
    echo "true";
}``

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76488987/16152434

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if( in_array($a, array($b,$c,$d)) ){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You should have closed this question as duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

That is valid code but not logically correct.

If you have lots of values then you could do something like this.

```
if(in_array($a,array($b,$c,$d))) {
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it is the same as @Engineer wrote a minute ago.

Comment: @Fluffeh: And the same as ascii-lime wrote 9 months ago.

Comment: @FelixKling No doubt that there are duplicates, just went as far as looking at this Q&A to see duplicates :)

Answer (score 1):

That both are not same as `||` is boolean operator and will always return `true` or `false`. So in second statement, you are comparing if `$a` is `true` or `false`.

You can use `in_array` to compare if `$a` exists in `array($b, $c, $d)`

Answer (score 1):

don't know why You want to do some sort of thing, but You can put b,c,d in array and call in_array function to search for elements. 
Still I can't understand why You want to short and simple code make short and not simple.

Comment: Because I have about 15 values which I want get me in the IF

Comment: so in_array as suggested by me and others.